# ngFor shows empty items after array.push

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have this in my template:

```
<input type="button" value="add" (click)="addEnvVar()"/>
<div *ngFor="let envVar of application.env_vars">
    <input type="text" name="key" [(ngModel)]="envVar.key">
    <input type="text" name="value" [(ngModel)]="envVar.value">
</div>
```

The code behind `addEnvVar()`:
`this.application.env_vars.push({key:'', value:''});`

When the component is initialized, there is one object inside `env_vars` and it is rendered just fine (the `<input>` fields are populated). After I click 'add', I can see in console that there are indeed two objects inside env_vars (the second is the 'empty' object I just added), and in the view there are indeed two `<div>`s for each `envVar`, but all 4   `<input>` fields **are empty**.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is that when `ngFor` produces more than one `div`, the inputs in each `div` all get the same hard-coded `name` attribute (in my case - "key" and "value"), and the value is somehow attached to that. I changed `name="key"` to `name="key_{{i}}"` (`i` is a template variable holding the `ngFor` index property).

Question is, is this the way to go? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Aren't you pushing empty values with {key:'', value:''} ? Then it makes sense nothing shows in the input field, since the model behind is also empty

Comment: @JonasMH After adding, I have 4 input fields. The two new input fields should be empty, but the first two should still be populated with the values of the the first object in the array which hasn't changed.

Comment: This is a case where you should probably use reactive forms rather than model-based forms, and use a FormArray.

Comment: Minimal example: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4JbCTk1WQdcYprXfUu2?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

The culprit with errors like this is mostly likely the default `trackBy` function which tracks the references. Even if the data hasn't changed, but the references change, it will tear down the DOM and re-build it, meaning all data inside the input fields will be cleared.

#### Component

```
trackBy(index) { return index }
```

#### Template

```
*ngFor="let envVar of application.env_vars; trackBy: trackBy"
```

Unfortunately I cannot test it without a reproduction. However, JB Nizet's comment is right and you should follow this advice; this is a task more suited for reactive forms, and not template forms.